# Why does cached_property always update the data?

Tags: django, django-signals

There is a model, in its geoposition field, `latitude` and `longitude` are stored, as a string, in this form '27 .234234234,53.23423423434'.

This field is provided by [django-geoposition](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition). Thanks to him it is very convenient to enter the address.

I also need to store the real address. I do not know whether to do this correctly, but I decided to use [geocoder](http://geocoder.readthedocs.io/api.html), and store the result in `cached_property`

```
class Address(models.Model):
    geoposition = GeopositionField(null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.City', null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.Country', null=True)
    entrance = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=4, blank=True)
    floor = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=4, blank=True)
    flat = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=4, blank=True)

    @cached_property
    def address(self):
        g = geocoder.yandex([
            str(self.geoposition).split(',')[0], 
            str(self.geoposition).split(',')[1]
        ],
        method='reverse', lang='ru-RU')
        return g.address


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.address:
            self.address()

        super(Address, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        if self.address:
            return '%s' % str(self.address)
        return '%s' % str(self.pk)
```

But the problem is that with every attempt to edit a model that is associated with the Address, I see that the property is being computed, and even in some cases I catch connection time out from external services.

I can not understand the reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was that in the `save ()` method, I did not call the `address` property, but the `address()` method, so there was no caching.